# Hiding UITableViewCell without touching UITableViewDataSource

Tags: ios, ios4, uitableview

I'm currently stuck at how to hide a UITableViewCell. I've already tried `[cell setHidden:YES];` but this leaves an empty space between the "to-hide" cell and the next cell. Also I want to **avoid** touching the UITableView's data source.

I'm more looking for a way to do it in a "`CSS display:none;`" fashion. Anyone solved that kind of problem or can point me to helpfull resources?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: robin's answer below is, I'm afraid the only way to go to achieve this. The datasource must be touched!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well currently there is no other way `to-hide` a cell in `UITableView` but you can file a bug report to apple if you think its necessary.

bugreport.apple.com.

But I will tell you not to cause its not that difficult to delete a cell, all you need to do is call this method on your UITableView object.

```
- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This would be the final solution (touching the data source). Let's wait a bit what others have to say, otherwise I'll go this way :/

Comment: This is the normal solution. delegates are ment to be written — and touched — by you.